# Python3 Function missing 3 required positional arguments

Tags: python, odoo

I try to write a copy function in odoo 14
but I get following Error:

```
  Odoo Server Error
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
      result = request.dispatch()
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 682, in dispatch
      result = self._call_function(**self.params)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 358, in _call_function
      return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
      return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 346, in checked_call
      result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 911, in __call__
      return self.method(*args, **kw)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 530, in response_wrap
      response = f(*args, **kw)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1363, in call_button
      action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1351, in _call_kw
      return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 396, in call_kw
      result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
      result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  Exception

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
      return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
    File "/vagrant/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
      raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
  TypeError: copy_func() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'cr', 'uid', and 'ids'
```

I have searched for solutions, but it can't copy successfully.

```
def copy_func(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    _logger.info('=== copy_func start ===')

    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        formbas_obj = self.pool.get('com.formmst')
        defaults = {
            'form_no': record.form_no,
            'com_orgbas_id': record.com_orgbas_id.id if record.com_orgbas_id else False,
        }
        formbas_obj.copy(cr, uid, record.com_formmst_id.id, defaults)
    _logger.info('=== copy_func end ===')
```

I call this function when I click the Copy button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEiil.png)

```
<record id="form_com_formbas_copy_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">form.com.formbas.copy.wizard</field>
    <field name="model">com.formbas.copy.wizard</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group col="4">
                <field name="com_formmst_id"/>
                <newline/>
                <field name="form_no"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button string="Copy" name="copy_func" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                or
                <button string="Cancel" special="cancel" type="object" class="oe_link"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

I'm struggling at this for quite some time. Any sort of help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Update the question to include the entire error traceback message, not just the final error.

Comment: This is not the code that caused that error.  Where, exactly, do you get that error?

Comment: Can you share the way you call the function?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you! I have updated the error message.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you! I have updated the error message.

Comment: The traceback says `formst_copy_func`, not `copy_func`.  Is this function a handler for a web request?  Are you passing `cr`, `uid`, and `ids` as parameters or POST fields to that request?

Comment: @BuddyBobIII Thank you!  I have updated the image show the way how to call the function.

Comment: That's not what I meant lol. I would like to see how you called the function in your code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry, I changed the function' s name. I just want to copy value of fields to a new form.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII Got it LOL. I update the code.I call the function in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use new ORM API. For that, remove function signatures - **cr, uid, ids, context=None**

Old api

```
def afun(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
```

New API

```
def afun(self):
```

---

```
def copy_func(self):
    _logger.info('=== copy_func start ===')

    for record in self:
        formbas_obj = self.env['com.formmst'].search(['id', '=', 121])
        defaults = {
            'form_no': record.form_no,
            'com_orgbas_id': record.com_orgbas_id.id if record.com_orgbas_id else False,
        }
        formbas_obj.write(defaults)
    _logger.info('=== copy_func end ===')
```

in your function, specify exact object for **formbas_obj** to write **default values** to.

[REference](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/what-is-self-env-92304)

Comment: @XUN Glad it helps. Please accept answer so it can help others too.